# Highlight Vertex or point on face in object mode

Tags: mesh, scripting, 3d-view, add-on

I am writing an add on with the API. I am creating a vertex at a chosen location on the object and would like to highlight it in the object mode for further reference. Is there a way to do this with the blender API?

So far the closest I have found is importing GPU and draw the points on the 3D view. They still show when they should be obstructed by an object though, so this is not an ideal solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.